# Can this PHP function be improved?

Tags: php, javascript

Below is some code I am working on for a navigation menu, if you are on a certain page, it will add a "current" css class to the proper tab.

I am curious if there is a better way to do this in PHP because it really seems like a lot of code to do such a simple task?  My pages will also have a jquery library already loaded, would it be better to set the tab with jquery instead of PHP?  Any tips appreciated

```
<?PHP

active_header('page identifier goes here'); //ie; 'home' or 'users.online'

function active_header($page_name)
{

    // arrays for header menu selector
    $header_home = array('home' => true);
    $header_users = array(
        'users.online' => true,
        'users.online.male' => true, 
        'users.online.female' => true, 
        'users.online.friends' => true, 
        'users.location' => true, 
        'users.featured' => true, 
        'users.new' => true, 
        'users.browse' => true, 
        'users.search' => true, 
        'users.staff' => true
    );
    $header_forum = array('forum' => true);
    $header_more = array(
        'widgets' => true, 
        'news' => true, 
        'promote' => true, 
        'development' => true, 
        'bookmarks' => true, 
        'about' => true
    );
    $header_money = array(
        'account.money' => true, 
        'account.store' => true, 
        'account.lottery' => true, 
        'users.top.money' => true
    );
    $header_account = array('account' => true);
    $header_mail = array(
        'mail.inbox' => true, 
        'mail.sentbox' => true, 
        'mail.trash' => true, 
        'bulletins.post' => true, 
        'bulletins.my' => true, 
        'bulletins' => true
    );

    // set variables if there array value exist
    if (isset($header_home[$page_name])){
        $current_home = 'current';
    }else if (isset($header_users[$page_name])){
        $current_users = 'current';
    }else if (isset($header_forum[$page_name])){
        $current_forum = 'current';
    }else if (isset($header_more[$page_name])){
        $current_more = 'current';
    }else if (isset($header_money[$page_name])){
        $current_money = 'current';
    }else if (isset($header_account[$page_name])){
        $current_account = 'current';
    }else if (isset($header_mail[$page_name])){
        $current_mail = 'current';
    }

    // show the links
    echo '<li class="' . (isset($current_home) ? $current_home : '') . '"><a href=""><em>Home</em></a></li>';
    echo '<li class="' . (isset($current_users) ? $current_users : '') . '"><a href=""><em>Users</em></a></li>';
    echo '<li class="' . (isset($current_forum) ? $current_forum : '') . '"><a href=""><em>Forum</em></a></li>';
    echo '<li class="' . (isset($current_more) ? $current_more : '') . '"><a href=""><em>More</em></a></li>';
    echo '<li class="' . (isset($current_money) ? $current_money : '') . '"><a href=""><em>Money</em></a></li>';
    echo '<li class="' . (isset($current_account) ? $current_account : '') . '"><a href=""><em>Account</em></a></li>';
    echo '<li class="' . (isset($current_mail) ? $current_mail : '') . '"><a href=""><em>Mail</em></a></li>';
}

?>
```

Comment: Please try to wrap your code blocks at 80 (or 120) characters if possible. It makes it extremely difficult to view online, and very annoying to have to fix something you should have done. It's also great from a code maintenance & readability perspective if you were to code like this to begin with.

Comment: @hobodave I see that is much easiar on the eyes, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May as well throw in my lot. Output is restricted to match that given in the original question.

```
<?PHP

active_header('page identifier goes here'); //ie; 'home' or 'users.online'

function active_header($page_name)
{
    // Unified array
    $headers = array(
        'Home' => array('home' => true),
        'Users' => array(
            'users.online' => true,
            'users.online.male' => true, 
            'users.online.female' => true, 
            'users.online.friends' => true, 
            'users.location' => true, 
            'users.featured' => true, 
            'users.new' => true, 
            'users.browse' => true, 
            'users.search' => true, 
            'users.staff' => true
        ),
        'Forum' => array('forum' => true),
        'More' => array(
            'widgets' => true, 
            'news' => true, 
            'promote' => true, 
            'development' => true, 
            'bookmarks' => true, 
            'about' => true
        ),
        'Money' => array(
            'account.money' => true, 
            'account.store' => true, 
            'account.lottery' => true, 
            'users.top.money' => true
        ),
        'Account' => array('account' => true),
        'Mail' => array(
            'mail.inbox' => true, 
            'mail.sentbox' => true, 
            'mail.trash' => true, 
            'bulletins.post' => true, 
            'bulletins.my' => true, 
            'bulletins' => true
        )
    );

    foreach($headers as $header => &$pages) {
        echo '<li class="';
        if(isset($pages[$page_name])) echo 'content';
        echo '"><a href=""><em>', $header, '</em></a></li>';
    }            

}

?>
```

I'm not a fan of mixing up the code with the output, but it'll do for example.

PHP hint of the day: Don't use string concatenation if you're just echoing a string

Comment: Nice code thanks!  1 other thing, with this example how would I be able to set the URL links that are shown for each menu item as well?

Comment: I know this sounds crazy but I just realized something in my code, this was all based off my old site that I am re-doing.  The old site loaded every page through the index file (ie; index.php?p=users.online ) the new project will be like this (ie; index.php ,mail.php) So on subpages of a menu item it was more complex like this but on my new site I will be able to set a page name in each file. So in pages that are under users, I can save a page name as Users for all pages.In other words I won't need the big array, just the main items like Home, users, mail, etc..So I can simplify this even more

Answer (score 4):

The two very large blocks of code at the bottom could be reduced drastically to a simple loop:

```
<?php

foreach (array('home', 'users', 'forum' /* ... */ ) as $item) {
  $ar = "header_$item";
  echo '<li class="', (isset($$ar[$page_name]) ? 'current' : '')
    , '"><a href=""><em>', ucword($item), '</em></a></li>';
}

?>
```

Comment: a good example of variable variables. http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: Personally, I don't think the solution lies in _more_ arrays. I find that the bottom chunk of code is probably the clearest in what he's got so far.

Answer (score 3):

You should try not to print `<li class="">` or something like that; it looks messy. I've moved the checking of whether this page or not is the one to highlight to a seperate function in case you end up changing the layout of `$applicable_list`.

```
<?php
function active_header($page) {
    $applicable_list = array(
        "home" => array("home"),
        "users" => array(
            "users.online", "users.online.male", "users.online.female", "users.online.friends", 
            "users.location", "users.featured", "users.new", "users.browse", "users.search", "users.staff"
        ), 
        "forum" => array("forum"),
        "more" => array("widgets", "news", "promote", "development", "bookmarks", "about"),
        "money" => array("account.money", "account.store", "account.lottery", "users.top.money"),
        "account" => array("account"),
        "mail" => array("mail.inbox", "mail.sentbox", "mail.trash", "bulletins.post", "bulletins.my", "bulletins")
    );
    $pages = array_keys($applicable_list);

    function is_active_page($page, $category, $category_pages_list) {
        return array_key_exists($category, $category_pages_list) && in_array($page, $category_pages_list[$category]);
    }
    foreach($pages as $key => $category) {
        printf('<li%s><a href="#"><em>%s</em></a></li>' . "\n", 
            (is_active_page($page, $category, $applicable_list) ? ' class="current"' : ''),
            ucwords($category)
        );
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Nice I didn't even know you could define a function inside a function like that!

Comment: I am trying your example but there is an error on the line where is_active_page() is called, 6th line up from the bottom, Also how would I be able to set a different URL for each item in the links that are shown?  Thanks for the help

Comment: I suppose you could use a set of URLs in an array? I replicated the original code - I don't know what you mean when you say "set a different URL for each item" - at least, not what you mean to say.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using the page names as array keys you could simply have arrays of the page names, and then compare using [in_array](http://www.php.net/in_array)`($page_name, $array)`, rather than `isset($array[$page_name])`.

This should happily work alongside the alterations from @meager, and would allow the static bits of code at the top to shrink a little.

Comment: `in_array` does a linear search over the array whereas `isset` simply checks the index.  In short, using `in_array` is slow compared to `isset`.

Answer (score 1):

Consolidate your arrays, or put all that logic in another well-named function. My example consolidates the arrays.

```
// it's ugly, but at least the ugliness
// is confined to only _one_ array ;)
$map_pages_to_navitem = array(
    'home' => 'home',
    'users.online' => 'users',
    'users.online.male' => 'users',
    'users.online.female' => 'users',
    'users.online.friends' => 'users',
    'users.location' => 'users',
    'users.featured' => 'users',
    'users.new' => 'users',
    'users.browse' => 'users',
    'users.search' => 'users',
    'users.staff' => 'users',
    'forum' => 'forum',
    'widgets' => 'more',
    'news' => 'more',
    'promote' => 'more',
    'development' => 'more',
    'bookmarks' => 'more',
    'about' => 'more',
    'account.money' => 'money',
    'account.store' => 'money',
    'account.lottery' => 'money',
    'users.top.money' => 'money',
    'account' => 'account'),
    'mail.inbox' => 'mail', 
    'mail.sentbox' => 'mail', 
    'mail.trash' => 'mail', 
    'bulletins.post' => 'mail', 
    'bulletins.my' => 'mail', 
    'bulletins' => 'mail', 
);
$current = $map_pages_to_navitem[$page_name];

echo '<li class="'.($current=='home')?'current':''.'"><a href=""><em>Home</em></a></li>';
echo '<li class="'.($current=='users')?'current':''.'"><a href=""><em>Users</em></a></li>';
echo '<li class="'.($current=='forum')?'current':''.'"><a href=""><em>Forum</em></a></li>';
echo '<li class="'.($current=='more')?'current':''.'"><a href=""><em>More</em></a></li>';
echo '<li class="'.($current=='money')?'current':''.'"><a href=""><em>Money</em></a></li>';
echo '<li class="'.($current=='account')?'current':''.'"><a href=""><em>Account</em></a></li>';
echo '<li class="'.($current=='mail')?'current':''.'"><a href=""><em>Mail</em></a></li>';
```

Looking at the code, I also see the end result is to assign on `<li>` element a class attribute value. JavaScript will do this better than PHP.

So you could give each `<li>` an id and leave the assignment of the class attribute to JavaScript:

```
echo '<li id="home"><a href=""><em>Home</em></a></li>';
echo '<li id="users"><a href=""><em>Users</em></a></li>';
echo '<li id="forum"><a href=""><em>Forum</em></a></li>';
echo '<li id="more"><a href=""><em>More</em></a></li>';
echo '<li id="money"><a href=""><em>Money</em></a></li>';
echo '<li id="account"><a href=""><em>Account</em></a></li>';
echo '<li id="mail"><a href=""><em>Mail</em></a></li>';

echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo 'document.getElementById("'.$current.'").className = "current";';
          // you'll want to sanitize $current to avoid parse errors in your JS
echo '</script>'
```

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking about a javascript solution and the one you provide is really nice!  Do you think the javascript solution is more efficient?

Comment: Not particularly. It's just different, and in the end it's a matter of personal taste... but it makes things easier when you add more `<li>` elements in the future, since the JavaScript will find it for you, and you end up with fewer strings concatenated in output.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `switch` instead of extensive `if/else` for starters :-)

Comment: If you look closely the `switch` is checking if various different arrays are set, `switch` only works if you are checking multiple different values for the same variable.

Comment: `swith(true) { case $var1 == 'value': /* do something */ break;  case $var2 == 'value': /* do something */ break;}` However, id did miss what you caught and so this offers little advantage over the if/else.. still it is possible :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
    // set variables if there array value exist
if (isset($header_home[$page_name])){
    $current_home = 'current';
}else if (isset($header_users[$page_name])){
    $current_users = 'current';
}else if (isset($header_forum[$page_name])){
    $current_forum = 'current';
}else if (isset($header_more[$page_name])){
    $current_more = 'current';
}else if (isset($header_money[$page_name])){
    $current_money = 'current';
}else if (isset($header_account[$page_name])){
    $current_account = 'current';
}else if (isset($header_mail[$page_name])){
    $current_mail = 'current';
}
```

You can use variables variable ( http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php ), foreach and break to reduce this part of function

Comment: I disagree; using variable variables won't help make the code any more readable or easy to understand.

Comment: My mistake, I agree. PeterJCLaw solution is much more better. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any compelling reason to change your original code. It's very easy to read and understand, and easy enough to modify.  I also don't think there's any reason to use Javascript to set the tab indicator.  By using PHP, you cater to people who have javascript disabled, and I like to save Javascript for when it's truly needed.

Answer (score 0):

If not changing to "return htmlcode" from "printing htmlcode", i would at least add a second parameter for that.